# Flash drive showing up with 0kb space available

Tags: windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive, mount

I have a ocz Rally2 flash drive that has stopped working on one computer only (XP SP3). When I plug it in it shows up as E: but in disk management it is not present and if I select properties in explorer then it shows as having zero space available.

I have checked the drive in two other computers, one XP and the other Win7, both show the data and device correctly.

I managed to get it to work once before by removing all the old flash drive instances from device manage

```
cd C:\WINDOWS\system32
SET DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1
devmgmt.msc
```

then selecting show hidden devices and all the non connected devices show up and you can remove them. I did that and then was able to get the flash drive to connect properly.

Now I can't get it to attach correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From
>   http://ezinearticles.com/?Flash-Drive-Not-Detected?-Solution-is-Here&id=1526594
>
> Sometimes, even if the icon for
>   Removable disc appears under My
>   Computer,the drive may not work
>   properly as the complete capacity will
>   not be mounted in case of inadequate
>   power. You can check this by right
>   clicking on Removable Disc and then
>   clicking on Properties. If one this
>   window, both free and used space is
>   showing 0 KB then this can be the
>   possible problem. In order to fix any
>   issues related to inadequate power
>   supply you can purchase USB Power Hub
>   from any computer store and attach it
>   to the USB port. What it does is that
>   it will convert the low power supplied
>   by USB port to little high power.
>
> But, remember this problem generally
>   happens in case of old computers.
>   Before purchasing USB power hub, you
>   can also try the back port of your
>   computer if you are on Desktop.

It seems as though the computer is suffering from a lack of power. It is an older HP wx8200 dual xeon machine which has a really hot power supply. It is not my computer and the last time I was using it worked fine. This time the machine had been moved into a computer slot in a desk system.

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.